# How to open multiple urls in express.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to make a something like kind of url shortener.
Basically Url shortener makes a url to redirect some pages but the service I'm working on, has to open multiple urls at once.

So when user open a link from my site, It should opens multiple links at once.

I found a express API that opens a link. `res.direct`

but It opens only one link. Is there any ways to open multiple links at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: **No**

Express is a server side framework. So, Express is answering a Request, and works the same way all http servers works. If you have a request, you have a response. This is a 1:1

**Workaround:**

If you want to open multiple links, you can achieve that in the client side. You can server a response with express with an array of urls. Then in the client, using javascript (jQuery, angular, etc), you can open several pages in same number of windows.